# Cannot get color plot of single band tiff image with rasterio

Tags: geotiff, rasterio

I want to work with TIFF files of aeronautical charts supplied by the FAA [here](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/vfr/).

The python module rasterio seems to be the right tool for my purposes and I’ve been through several tutorials and reference docs.  They all work for me, *but not with the the data I want to use*.  I cannot seem to get it to display properly in color.

The main difference seems to be that my data is single band (as reported by dataset.count) whereas all the tutorials have three or more bands.

For example, the following code should display the chart:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
dataset = rasterio.open ('Green_Bay_101/Green Bay SEC 101.tif')
show(dataset)
```

The resulting plot has the colors all wrong.

[Screen shot of image produced by above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVVLR.jpg)

But it should look like this:

[Screen shot of image shown with macOS Finder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MykQz.jpg)

I’m sure that I’m missing something basic, but I cannot find it.  Would someone please point it out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have posted this on [Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377815/) where it probably belongs.  There is more information there.  Sorry for cross posting.